# Getting a error that my image cannot be displayed because of errors

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an error message that says my image cannot be displayed because of errors.  I looked at previous solutions to the problem but none has created any success.  I made sure there are no blank lines, i have the html and the php seperate, and i have the right information before the header.  Any help would be great as I think im missing something small.
Code is below.

html:

```
            <?php
        $images = "SELECT product_images.img_name, product_images.img_tag, product_images.img_family, product_images.img_id FROM product_images
INNER JOIN product_list
ON product_images.img_tag = product_list.product_tag && product_images.img_family = product_list.name_family";
    $img_list = mysql_query($images);
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($img_list))  {
        $img_name = $rows['img_name'];
        $img_tag = $rows['img_tag'];
        $img_family = $rows['img_family'];
        $img_id = $rows['img_id'];
        //echo $img_name;
?>
                <div>
                  <img src="view.php?imgid=<?php echo $img_id; ?>" />
                </div>  
<?php 
    }
?>
```

php:

```
<?php
require_once('april25_connect.php');
$dir = "product_images/";
$img = $_GET['imgid'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM product_images WHERE img_id = '$img'";
//echo $query,'<br>';
$newid = mysql_query($query);
if (!$newid) {
    echo "Query '$newid' failed <br />\n";
    echo "Error: ".mysql_error()." <br />\n";
    exit;
}else{
    while($returned_id = mysql_fetch_array($newid)) {
    $name = $returned_id['img_name'];
    $tag =  $returned_id['img_tag'];
    $family = $returned_id['img_family'];
    header ("Content-type: image/jpeg; image/gif; image/png");
    $fullpath = $dir.$name;
    echo $fullpath;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Was it that difficult to copy the original error message or you think that inaccurate explanation of the issue is helpful?

Comment: No need to be a jerk.

The image “view-source:http://www.apriltwentyfive.com/test/view.php?imgid=1” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Comment: why adding the header?, you are just returning a path

Comment: @Amir Muslim: have you tried to see the exact server response and error logs?

Comment: please provide the error messages you are getting

Comment: @Hawili: there is no php errors - he just returns path to the image instead of its contents

Comment: how do I see the exact server response and error log?

Comment: @AmirMuslim btw, you a huge SQL injection flaw. Sanitize your input, escape your SQL :(

Comment: Thanks, I saw that.  Essentially, I just store the name of the file in the database and try to display the fullpath based on where it is in the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're approach is wrong. Shouldn't your echo the $fullpath at the IMG html tag instead of the $img_id?

```
<img src="view.php?imgid=<?php echo $fullpath; ?>" />
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding it, but it's hard to tell by partly seeing the content of the script.

<strike>P.S. I don't see your script returning the $img_id var for use.</strike>

I checked your product_images/ directory, it's a level up, that makes it
    $dir = "../product_images/";

Comment: You helped me solve the problem by revealing that I was not displaying the right output.  I output the path but not the actual file in the directory.  Once I did that, it worked.  Thanks.